# How to apply the OpenCV threshold method to the morphology image ouput from the Skimage method?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I work with a code that removes large objects from an image based on a defined threshold.

The code that I am working with, saves the file after the **morphology** operation from the **skimage** module:

```
from skimage import measure, morphology

# EDIT: added blobs_labels calculation
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary        
blobs = img > img.mean()
blobs_labels = measure.label(blobs, background=1)
constant = 200

b = morphology.remove_small_objects(blobs_labels, constant)
# save the the pre-version which is the image is labelled with colors
plt.imsave('pre_version.png', b)
# read the pre-version
img = cv2.imread('pre_version.png', 0)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Now I would to directly apply the threshold method - without saving the image inbetween - to the morphology image output (b):

```
b = morphology.remove_small_objects(blobs_labels, constant)
img = cv2.threshold(b, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

However, if I change the code as stated above, I get the following error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1527:
>
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'cv::threshold'

My questions is, why can't I directly apply the threshold method to the morphology output?

Comment: Works fine on me. Are you sure you can read your image correctly ?

Comment: I added the code, that I am using to load the image. This code gives me the error above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us anything about `blobs_labels`, so it's difficult to be certain, but the problem is likely the data type of the image. `skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects` maintains the original data type, so if it is a type that `cv2` does not want, you will get an error. Converting to uint8 solves the problem on my end.

```py
import cv2
import skimage.morphology

blobs_labels = skimage.data.binary_blobs()
constant = 16
b = skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(blobs_labels, constant)
b = b.astype('uint8')
img = cv2.threshold(b, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Your code with the image reading worked probably because cv2 was converting the data to a type it could work with.

Comment: I added code on how I calculate the blobs_labels above. I will try your solution, thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that was helpful! Based on your suggestion, I was able to save the file. However, np.array_equiv(b.astype('uint8'), img) will now result in False, which implies that the values of the image have changed. any idea, why this is happening?

Comment: you can try `np.allclose` instead (that's better to test with floating point arrays). but it is possible that values were changed. try out different data types with cv2

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it! np.allclose(b.astype('uint8'), img) also returned false